# Inside Copying File section stopped working for batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, copy, archive

Any advice would be appreciated.

This was working until I put in the if exists to check if the file is in the destination directory. 
Overall: 
I am trying to :

- 1.read a list in text file get the file name to copy.
- 2.check if the file exists rename it the destination directory
- 3.move in the new one
- 4.The move the old to archive directory.

The code for ***item 3*** is not working (right after **@echo "Copying file"**)

***Code:***

```dos
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('type %~dp0list.txt') DO (
    if exist "%Dest_Dir%\%%a" (
        @echo File Found
        ren "%Dest_Dir%\%%a" %%a.%DATE_VAR%.RFC#_%number%.bkup  
        Set "backup=1"
        ) else  @echo no file exits 
    @echo 
    @echo "Copying file"
    FOR /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%f IN (*%%a*) DO (
        @echo "inside Copying file "  %%f
        SET "SRC=%%~dpf"
        SET DEST=!SRC:%SEARCH_DIR%=%DEST_DIR%!
        xcopy /S /I "%%~f" "!DEST!"
    )
)
If "backup"=="1" (
    @echo *INSIDE MOVE*
    Rem Copy "%Dest_Dir%\*.*.*.*.bkup" "%ARCHIVE_DIR%\*.*.*.*.bkup"
    Copy "%Dest_Dir%\*bkup" "%ARCHIVE_DIR%\*bkup"
    Del "%Dest_Dir%\*.*.*.*.bkup"
    SET "backup=0"
    )
```

Comment: How did you edit that to format better; Notepad++ and copy? Thank you for doing that. Looks much better.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that this was working given what is now showing. There have been so many edits that it's impossible to tell what is original code and what is attempts to highlight/bold/italic for emphasis. You should post your original code by cut-and pasting it, then select the code and press `{}` to indent it which will render it in a readable form. If you want to post simply a section of the code (preferred if you have a long program) please indicate any non-standard conditions in effect (eg delayedexpansion).

Comment: `!` will be ineffective if `delayedexpansion` is not invoked and `If "backup"=="1"` will never be true.

Comment: Thank you.The delayedexpansion is invoked at the beginning. I will post original code for deeper review.

Comment: Full code is too long. Can it be attached?

Comment: No - just extract the relevant section, but include the `delayedexpansion` instruction so that the code you post would represent the conditions under which your code is running. For instance, in your posted code, you have `%%a` surrounded by asterisks - probably the result of attempted highlighting and edits. Best to start afresh.

Comment: FOR /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%f IN (*%%a*) DO (
        @echo "inside Copying file "  %%f
        SET "SRC=%%~dpf"
        SET DEST=!SRC:%SEARCH_DIR%=%DEST_DIR%!
        xcopy /S /I "%%~f" "!DEST!"
    )

Comment: *%%a* is the actual code. It is part of the code that was working before.

Comment: At the top of the code I have: SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Comment: Found out problem: File names starting with a number do not work. If I start with a letter the script works fine.  1a.jpg vs a1.jpg.   "a1.jpg" works.